# Splunk: How to compute the difference of timestamps by id?

Tags: group-by, merge, splunk

I have such events:

Request:

```
 Request "id":"123-abc-456"
```

Response:

```
 Response "id":"123-abc-456"
```

With the following query

```
(index=something "Response") OR (index=something "Request") 
|rex field=_raw "id\":\"(?<id>[a-z0-9-]+)" 
| table _time id
```

I get a table which contains the `id` and `_time` field of one event. It looks like this:

```
_time id
2022-01-01 12:00:00:00 123-abc-456
2022-01-01 12:11:11:11 123-abc-456
```

Now, I am wondering if it is possible to maybe generate a new table with the difference of `_time` fields grouped by the `id` field? Or do I have to change my query upon in order to get a table like this and then compute the difference? But I do not know how to get such a table as below...

```
Requesttime id Reponsetime
2022-01-01 12:00:00:00 123-abc-456 2022-01-01 12:11:11:11
```

Thanks a lot in response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splunk can only compute the difference between timestamps when they're in epoch (integer) form.  Fortunately, `_time` is already in epoch form (automatically converted to text when displayed).

If Requesttime and Responsetime are in the same event/result then computing the difference is a simple `| eval diff=Responsetime - Requesttime`.

If the two timestamps are in different events/results then we can use the `range()` function to get their difference.

````
index=something "Request"
| rex field=_raw "id\":\"(?<id>[a-z0-9-]+)" 
| table _time id
| stats min(_time) as Requesttime, max(_time) as Responsetime, range(_time) as diff by id
```Format the timestamps manually```
| fieldformat Requesttime=strftime(Requesttime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:S")
| fieldformat Responsetime=strftime(Responsetime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:S")
| fieldformat diff=tostring(diff,"duration")
````

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very helpful and as always competent answer! I asked another question here on the topic how to get a timechart with these extracted values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70753282/splunk-how-to-get-a-timechart-regarding-the-extracted-time-values-for-which-ra

Answer (score 0):

There is a `%` missing before `S` in strftime in the accepted answer.

````
index=something "Request"
| rex field=_raw "id\":\"(?<id>[a-z0-9-]+)" 
| table _time id
| stats min(_time) as Requesttime, max(_time) as Responsetime, range(_time) as diff by id
```Format the timestamps manually```
| fieldformat Requesttime=strftime(Requesttime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
| fieldformat Responsetime=strftime(Responsetime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
| fieldformat diff=tostring(diff,"duration")
````