# Splunk: How to get a timechart regarding the extracted _time values for which range() was applied?

Tags: splunk, request-response

With the following query I get the stats about `Requesttime`, `Responsetime` and Request-Responsetime (`diff`) of a specific `id`:

```
(index=something "Request") OR (index=something "Response")
| rex field=_raw "id\":\"(?<id>[a-z0-9-]+)" 
| table _time id
| stats min(_time) as Requesttime, max(_time) as Responsetime, range(_time) as diff by id
```

What I now want to get is a timechart with the average `diff` per 1 minute.

I tried to replace the `stats` command by a second `table` command and by the `timechart` command but nothing did the job.

Note: `Requesttime` and `Reponsetime` are in different events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
(index=something "Request") OR (index=something "Response") 
| rex field=_raw "id\":\"(?<id>[a-z0-9-]+)" 
| stats earliest(_time) as earliestTime latest(_time) as latestTime by id
| eval duration=latestTime-earliestTime
| eval _time=earliestTime
| timechart span=1m avg(duration) as avgRequestResponseTime 
| fillnull value=0 avgRequestResponseTime
| eval avgRequestResponseTime=round(avgRequestResponseTime,4)
```

Comment: As you discovered, the `timechart` command requires the `_time` field.  Once you supplied that, `timechart` worked. This modification of the original query should also work.  `(index=something "Request") OR (index=something "Response")
| rex field=_raw "id\":\"(?<id>[a-z0-9-]+)" 
| table _time id
| stats min(_time) as Requesttime, max(_time) as Responsetime, range(_time) as diff, earliest(_time) as _time by id
| timechart span=1m avg(duration) as avgRequestResponseTime `

Answer (score 0):

[`timechart`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/timechart) requires the hidden field `_time` still exist - in this example, there is no `_time` field

So you're going to need to ["fake" your timechart](https://antipaucity.com/2020/08/18/how-to-timechart-possibly-better-than-timechart-in-splunk/#.Yeb43SxOlAc) - or you're going to need to get `_time` back somehow or other

Something along these lines should work:

```
index=ndx ("Request" OR "Response")
| rex field=_raw "id\":\"(?<id>[a-z0-9-]+)" 
| stats min(_time) as Requesttime, max(_time) as Responsetime, range(_time) as diff by id date_minute
| stats avg(diff) as avg by id date_minute
```

(I took out the extraneous first `| table` line, as it slows the search down, and `| stats` will yield a table when it's completed)